# How to obtain visible vertex indices and face indices using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, gpu

Is it possible to obtain visible vertex and/or face indices in OpenGL?

I have heard of unprojecting screen points from mouse clicks and then using some space-search algorithm to do the rest of the job. This seems to be somewhat inefficient.

I was wondering, but could not find on the internet, if it is possible to obtain the vertices directly from a GPU buffer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need that? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am trying to simulate a robot environment where I will test some map exploration tests. This requires to know which vertices the robot sees when it explores a given map.

Comment: I'd assign a unique color to each triangle, and then simply check colors of rendered pixels.

Comment: *"1D color search"* There would be no search involved. You say you want face indices, and you can easily encode an index as a color. So getting an index from a color would be a simple O(1) operation. Looks more efficient than unprojecting then searching for matching triangle to me. Also, you say you have 10^11 vertices, huh? With 3 floats per vertex, that's over 1 terabyte of data. You sure that's an actual amount?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat:  Each had around 1~3 X10^8 vertices.